# Swift - como descubro tamanho da tela do aparelho do usuário?

Tags: swift, mobile

Gostaria de saber como descubro o tamanho da tela que o usuário está utilizando ou o modelo de seu iPhone via
**Swift**. Sei apenas como fazer em Objective-C

## Resposta em Objective-C:

```
    CGFloat screenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    NSLog(@"Escala %f", screenScale);
    
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    NSLog(@"Bounds %@", screenBounds);
    
    CGSize screenSize = CGSizeMake(screenBounds.size.width * screenScale, screenBounds.size.height * screenScale);
    NSLog(@"Pixels %f", screenSize);        
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", screenSize];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Essa `extension` abaixo te ajuda a saber qual modelo do aparelho, logo você saberá qual o tamanho da tela.**

```
public extension UIDevice {

  var modelName: String {
    var systemInfo = utsname()
    uname(&systemInfo)
    let machineMirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.machine)
    let identifier = machineMirror.children.reduce("") { identifier, element in
      guard let value = element.value as? Int8 where value != 0 else { return identifier }
      return identifier + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(value)))
    }

    switch identifier {
    case "iPod5,1":                                 return "iPod Touch 5"
    case "iPod7,1":                                 return "iPod Touch 6"
    case "iPhone3,1", "iPhone3,2", "iPhone3,3":     return "iPhone 4"
    case "iPhone4,1":                               return "iPhone 4s"
    case "iPhone5,1", "iPhone5,2":                  return "iPhone 5"
    case "iPhone5,3", "iPhone5,4":                  return "iPhone 5c"
    case "iPhone6,1", "iPhone6,2":                  return "iPhone 5s"
    case "iPhone7,2":                               return "iPhone 6"
    case "iPhone7,1":                               return "iPhone 6 Plus"
    case "iPhone8,1":                               return "iPhone 6s"
    case "iPhone8,2":                               return "iPhone 6s Plus"
    case "iPhone8,4":                               return "iPhone SE"
    case "iPad2,1", "iPad2,2", "iPad2,3", "iPad2,4":return "iPad 2"
    case "iPad3,1", "iPad3,2", "iPad3,3":           return "iPad 3"
    case "iPad3,4", "iPad3,5", "iPad3,6":           return "iPad 4"
    case "iPad4,1", "iPad4,2", "iPad4,3":           return "iPad Air"
    case "iPad5,3", "iPad5,4":                      return "iPad Air 2"
    case "iPad2,5", "iPad2,6", "iPad2,7":           return "iPad Mini"
    case "iPad4,4", "iPad4,5", "iPad4,6":           return "iPad Mini 2"
    case "iPad4,7", "iPad4,8", "iPad4,9":           return "iPad Mini 3"
    case "iPad5,1", "iPad5,2":                      return "iPad Mini 4"
    case "iPad6,3", "iPad6,4", "iPad6,7", "iPad6,8":return "iPad Pro"
    case "AppleTV5,3":                              return "Apple TV"
    case "i386", "x86_64":                          return "Simulator"
    default:                                        return identifier
    }
  }
}
```

**Exemplo de uso:**

```
let iPhoneName = UIDevice.currentDevice().modelName

switch iPhoneName {
case "iPhone 4s", "iPhone 4":
  break
case "iPhone 5", "iPhone 5s":
  break
default:
  break
}
```

**Segue um guia dos tamanhos das telas dos iPhones:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

A tradução desse código para Swift é a seguinte:

```
let screenScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
NSLog("Escala \(screenScale)")

let screenBounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
NSLog("Bounds \(screenBounds)")

let screenSize = CGSizeMake(screenBounds.size.width * screenScale, screenBounds.size.height * screenScale)
NSLog("Pixels \(screenSize)")
let result = "\(screenSize)"
```

Lembrando que a gente nunca deve tratar a tela como *pixels*, mas sim como *points*. A *scale* da tela serve para você decidir como renderizar desenhos ou imagens manualmente, por exemplo. O sistema que deve tratar da conversão de *points* pra *pixels*. Leitura recomendada: [iOS Drawing Concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html)

Um outro recurso interessante é a utilização de *Size Classes*, que abstraem a questão das dimensões da tela. Mais detalhes aqui: [Adaptivity and Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html)